# Effective way to test for performance impacts of Spectre and Meltdown patches on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, security, performance, patch, vulnerabilities

Much has been discussed about the potential performance impacts of patching systems for Spectre and Meltdown.

What is an effective way to test for performance impacts of Spectre and Meltdown patches on Windows, in particular Windows 7?

Comment: 3rd party benchmark suites which to massive CPU tests

Comment: What I want to find is anecdotal - but accurate - information.  For example, a Visual Studio solution build on my good system before the patches always took XX seconds, and after the patches it takes YY seconds.  I want to know how it will affect the things *I* have to waste time waiting on.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest test is built into Windows - the Windows Experience Index.

In Control Panel, System and Security, select "Check the Windows Experience Index" under System and click on "Rate this computer".
Windows run some tests for about 1-2 minutes and updates the Windows Experience Index, assessing key system components on a scale of 1.0 to 7.9.

You may also run benchmark products, of which maybe the best known is
[PCMark](https://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/pcmark10),
free for home use, download from
[here](https://www.futuremark.com/support/downloads).